# Base 64 Image size increase more than the actual size

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, base64

I am getting the Base 64 string regarding image, after getting the data I will replace the string to base 64, My code is this

```
const buf = Buffer.from(base64String.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ''),
'base64');
const imagedata = {
    Key: `${customname}.${imageextension}`,
        Body: buf,
        ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
};
```

After this I will upload the image on AWS S3, I Noticed that when I upload the image its actual size will be 400 kb, But after uploading on AWS S3 same image size will around 2MB.

I know base 64 will increase the size of 30 to 40 % but in my case its too heavy,
Any one suggest me how to solve this,

I am on Nodejs, any help is really appreciated.

Question Updated
Image Extension is completely depend upon user.

Question Updated.
I created the function which return the size of base 64 in kb.

```
const calculateImageSize = (base64String) =>{
    let padding, inBytes, base64StringLength;
    if (base64String.endsWith("==")) padding = 2;
    else if (base64String.endsWith("=")) padding = 1;
    else padding = 0;

    base64StringLength = base64String.length;
    console.log(base64StringLength)
    inBytes = (base64StringLength / 4) * 3 - padding;
    console.log(inBytes);
    this.kbytes = inBytes / 1000;
    console.log(inBytes / 1000 + "KB");
    return this.kbytes;
}
```

After that I i uploaded the image (1.43kb), on Nodejs pass the string to function for getting the size in kb.

calculateImageSize(req.body.image)`return 41.3 kb`

Means somehow I have to compress the size at the time of uploading..
Any help is really appreciated again
cr

Comment: How did you ascertain that the file which is 2MB in S3 actually takes up only 400KB locally?

Comment: Your options are to either avoid the Bas64 encoding or to reduce the size of the base image. As you said, Base64 will inherently increase the size and there is no way going around that.

Comment: @VLAZ The OP already knows this, and is asking about an apparent discrepancy in the compression ratio.

Comment: After uploading on s3, when I download that image its size will be around 2 MB

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen to be honest, I don't think it's completely clear whether OP wants to understand the difference or how to avoid the large size. OP - what are you after?

Comment: @Aks I'm not asking about S3, which you've already made clear.  How did you verify that the original file, before base 64 encoding, is only 400KB?

Comment: I just wanted to know that why this thing happens and I want to reduce the size

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen On my local system an image is saved on desktop which size is 400 kb, (checked through properties of image), after that same image upload on s3 and then same image download through s3 will be downloaded on desktop. When I see the property of that image its size will around 2 MB

Comment: @Aks Why are you encoding to base64? Is there a problem with uploading the image as-is?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I want to upload an image on AWS S3, so there is two option, first one is Binary and second one is Base64, For some reason i don't pick binary, so I used base64

Comment: Perhaps try binary?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein That was my usecase that I want to use only base64, I want to know the reason that why image is growing the size from 400kb to around 2MB, generally base64 will increase the size of 30% more than the actual size. I want to reduxe the size

Comment: How are you doing the conversion binary to base64? Are you only reading it? Or are you somehow drawing it it somewhere and getting a base64 version of this drawing? The latter sounds like the most plausibe reason for such an increase: You might have converted a JPEG image to a PNG one, or simply lost an high compression scheme.

Comment: It is quite possible that it is storing the file as the base64-encoded version. That is, it could be treating your base64 code as binary. To determine whether this is the case, take a look at the object in S3 and see whether it contains readable base64 code.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein even though, as OP said, they should only have an increase of 34% not 500%

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I converted the image through base 64 string, then send to Backend API which will store the image on S3, On Backend Side when API Called I simply use imagedata variable (mentioned on my question) and then use `s3Bucket.putObject(imagedata, (err) => {
       if (err) {
        
        console.log('Oops! we are facing some technical issue')
       }`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein after putObject image uploaded on s3 with the provided extension. There is no conversion of image extension. Whatever extension user uploaded, same extension stored on S3

Comment: You'll need to look in the file to determine what is happening. Try it on a very small image (eg one pixel) and then show us the output that was generated in the S3 object.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I downloaded jpg image from web which is around 1.41kb. After uploaded on S3, when Its size shows 41.3kb. I downloaded that Image, Same size i.e 41.3kb

Comment: Excellent! Can you open the 41KB image file and does it show the same picture? Have you looked at the contents of the file? (Perhaps you can link us to it, or describe its contents?)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes That image will exactly look like older one. No changes at all. Dear I updated my Question, kindly visit my question. Thanks in advance